# How can I update a plone page via a script?

Tags: python, plone

I have a large amount of automatically generated html files that I would like to push to my Plone website with a script. I currently generate the files, log into Plone, click edit on each individual page and copy and paste the html into the editor. I'd like to automate this. It would be nice to retain the plone versioning, have a auto generated comment for the edit, and come from a specific user.

I've read and tried Webdav with little luck at getting it working consistently and know that there is a way to connect to plone via ftp, but haven't tried it. I'm not sure if these are the methods that I need.

My google searches aren't leading me to anything useful. Any ideas on where to start looking for a solution to this? Or any tips on implementing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can script anything in Plone via the following methods:

- Through-the-web via API calls (e.g. XML-RPC, wsapi, etc.)
- The `bin/instance run` script provided by [plone.recipe.zope2instance](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zope2instance) (See [charm](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/charm/1.0b4) for an example of this).

You can also use a migration framework like:

- [collective.transmogrifier](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.transmogrifier/)

which allows you to write migration code, and trigger it via GenericSetup or Browser view. Additionally, there are applications written on top of Transmogrifier aimed roughly at what you are describing, the most popular of which is:

- [funnelweb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/funnelweb/1.0)

I would recommend that you consider using or writing a Transmogrifier "blueprint(s)" to do your import, and **execute the pipeline** with a tool that makes that easy:

- [mr.migrator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.migrator/1.0b4)

You can find blueprints by [searching PyPI for "transmogrify"](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=transmogrify&submit=search). One popular set of blueprints is:

- [quintagroup.transmogrifier](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/quintagroup.transmogrifier/0.4)

One of the main attractions to the Transmogrifier approach, aside from getting the job done, is the ability to share useful blueprints with others.

Comment: I found http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-community-developer-documentation/introduction/developermanual which is very appealing. I use Sphinx extensively and it offers much of what I may need for my html generation. These guys from plone push their sphinx doc to a plone instance with this tool: https://github.com/collective/collective.developermanual. I gave a shot at building collective.deverlopermanual, but it seemed to download and the eggs for about every package in the plone repos! I haven't gotten it to work locally, but it seems to make use of most of what you've posted.

Answer (score 2):

I think [transmogrifier](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.transmogrifier/) is the best tool for this job, but this will definitely be a programming task no matter how you do it.  It's used for many such migration jobs such as [migrating from drupal](http://www.sixfeetup.com/blog/transmogrifier-a-pipeline-for-easing-migration-into-plone).

Comment: I've been reading over the documentation for many of these options. The transmogrifier certainly seems complex. My familiarity with Plone is strong enough yet to get the complete picture. I'm looking at funnelweb and some of the layers on top of transmogrifier and trying things out.

Comment: I think the task you're trying to accomplish just is that complex.  So you might want to rethink your requirements and the way you're thinking about the problem.  But if you decide to move forward with it as you're thinking about it, I'd encourage you to be leery of trying to *avoid* this complexity.  Transmogrify is well maintained and supported so exercise caution with adopting something that promises to remove that complexity, it's likely to be more fragile than just learning how to do this yourself.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I'll give transmogrifier a shot and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

There's an add-on, wsapi4plone.core that pumazi at WebLion started that provides web services for portals which you can then hook into. You can create, modify, delete content via XML-RPC calls. The only caveat is that it doesn't yet work with Collections (criteria specifically).

project: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wsapi4plone.core 
docs: http://packages.python.org/wsapi4plone.core/

You can also do it programmatically by hooking into the ZODB via Python (zopepy or some other method).

These should get you started:

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/manipulating-plone-objects-programmatically/reading-and-writing-field-values - you should be able to get an understanding of accessors and mutators (setters and getters), in your case you are going to be more than likely working with obj.Text (getter) and obj.setText (setter).

https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/wiki/AutomatingObjectCreation - lots of examples (slightly outdated but still relevant)

Comment: I like the look of wsapi4plone.core. The documentation looks great too. It seems to have the simplicity that I'm looking for. I'll start testing out these different options that have been provided.

Comment: I'm upvoting aclark's response. All of these are options are viable. It really comes down to your environment and comfort level.

Answer (score 0):

http://plone.org/documentation/faq/upload-images-files

Try to enable Webdav or ftp in Plone, then you can access Plone via webdav or ftp clients, pushing the html files. Plone (Zope) will recognises the html files as Pages.